# IBM Watson. natural-language. Get :401 Invalid credentials, but they are correct. from java sdk

Tags: java, sdk, ibm-cloud

Using java sdk.  Running examples: com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.natural_language_classifier.v1;

Replaced userName, pw pasted from IBM site
get:SEVERE: POST https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers/%3Csentiment%3E/classify, status: 401, error: Not Authorized

core.src.main.java.com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.UnauthorizedException: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. Tip: Did you set the Endpoint?

IBM site references:"url": "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api",
Example code has:  .../natural-language-classifier

Tried both. Using /..understanding returns "404, error: not found"

Comment: What exactly is being asked here? Please explain what you are trying to do as well as the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the `classify` method with `Sentiment`

See `https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers/%3Csentiment%3E/classify`

The code below is working for me. You just need to replace `username` and `password`

```
NaturalLanguageClassifier service = new NaturalLanguageClassifier();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>");

Classification classification = service.classify("<classifier-id>", "Is it sunny?").execute();
System.out.println(classification);
```